# C language: Is there a way to choose options between temperatures from fahrenheit to celsius and celsius to fahrenheit?

Tags: c

C language: Is there a way to choose options between temperatures from fahrenheit to celsius and celsius to fahrenheit ?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    //Local declarations
    float fah,cen;
    //statements
    printf("Enter the temp in fah :");
    scanf("%f",&fah);
    cen=(fah-32)*5/9;
    printf("The centigrade temp is %f",&cen);
    printf("\nEnter the temp in centigrade:");
    scanf("%f",&cen);
    fah=(cen*9)/5+32;
    printf("The fahrenheit temp is %f",fah);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Enter the temp in fah: 300
The Centigrade temp is 148.888885
Enter temp in centigrade : 148.88885 
The Fahrenheit temp is : 300
```

Help:

Is there any way to modify the code so that user can choose either fahrenheit to celsius or celsius to fahrenheit. If he want to convert celsius to fahrenheit he could choose that?

Comment: Of course it's possible. The simplest would be to enter the number with a unit, and parse the input string. Then output the same temperature in the other unit.

Comment: What @JeanClaudeArbaut said. Just to illustrate, the input `"100f"` (or `"100F"`, maybe `"100 f"`) outputs 37C. If you want other units, just add them to the output... `"37C 100F 450K 1.03H"` (values are very rounded, H is made up)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `if` & `else` common conditions in this case? You should learn it first. And take care of learning and searching before asking any question here or you may get downvotes in future.

Take an example:

```
char ch;
printf("Your choice: ");
scanf("%c", ch);
```

And condition:

```
if (ch == 'f' || ch == 'F') {
    // Fahrenheit
} else if (ch == 'c' || ch == 'C') {
    // Celsius
} else {
    printf("No such option.\n");
}
```

Or

Suppose you've desired to get input from user just by C/F on `scanf()`, you can achieve in a more dynamic way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float constant, result;
    char expression;

    printf("Input a constant number and expression: ");
    scanf("%f%c", &constant, &expression); // e.g. 98.6F ==> 37.00C

    if (expression == 'c' || expression == 'C')
        // to Fahrenheit
        result = (9.0 * constant) / 5.0 + 32.0;
    else if (expression == 'f' || expression == 'F')
        // to Celsius
        result = (5.0 * (constant - 32.0) / 9.0);
    else {
        printf("No such option found.");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Result: %.2f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```